# Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'MasterPage' exists in both 'c:\~\App_Web_ogmril5q.DLL' and 'c:\~\App_Web_ogmril5q.DLL'

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have 2 master pages inside one ASP.Net website. It work fine without publishing website. After publishing the website on the web server, one of the master pages works fine, but when I want to access the page that is linked with the second master page it gives me the above error. But the weird thing is that the error paths are in c\ drive of my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this has happened in the past [rare but I saw it once in production] you need to clear out the contents of your shadow copy folders for your application.  These are usually in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files but the error path in your exception details will tell you where.

Answer (score 0):

when copying one web page/user control to create another web page/User Control . After copying one userControl to create another, I neglected to change the partial class name in the .cs of the new userControl and the 'Inherits=' in the .aspx file. Fixing those class names stopped the error from occurring. I suppose the easiest fix to avoid this is to just create new userControls each time using the wizard rather than copying and pasting an existing userControl.

as ex
if we copied the main master page to create another master page, both of them will have the same inherit and that what would create the problem so change the class name and then change the inherit with the new class name or always add new items rather than copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

There are various cs0433 errors that can cause this to occur.

Basically, if you like I did, try and compile the same project with different versions of Visual Studio, they may likely use a different version of the .Net Compilers and libraries.

Therefore, some built assemblies will be duplicated causing differing pointers to the same functionality, but with varying .Net CLR's

What solved it for me, was to recreate the folder from "Virgin Code Files", but with a slightly different name such as "Project1", "Project2", etc..

Then you can rebuild the project from scratch with the correct Visual Studio version, which for me was VS2019 and then "Bob's your uncle :)" No more errors.